# SQL Storedprocedure trace other than profiler

Tags: c#, .net, sql

To capture what are the Stored procedures are being hit in Production environment the profiler would be used. Whether it would be slowdown the environment? Whether it will affect the performance? If so, what are the alternative to trace the SP hits without affecting the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the profiler tool, you can create traces directly on the server via stored procedures

[Introducing SQL Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Historically, such tracing consumed fewer resources than using profiler - although, of course, all tracing must consume *some* resource.